# Parse JSON-like string into object using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, jsonparser

I have a problem about using JSON-like string parser: sometimes users will not input a correct strict JSON string. For example:

```js
input = 
"name: John, 
age: 20, 
products: [
  { id : 100, name: flower },
  { id : 101, name: snack },
], 
home: New York,
education: {
  highSchool: {
    name: Stuyvesant High School,
    GPA: 3.2
  },
  college: {
    name: Fordham University,
    GPA: 2.8
  }
}"
```

The input above is not able to parse using `JSON.parse()` because both key and value does not fit contained by `""` (`name: John` instead of `"name": "John"`)

How can we get the expected output like this:

```js
console.log(customParser(input));
//expected
/*
name: "John",
age: 20,
products: (2) [{...}, {...}]
home: "New York"
education: (2) {highSchool: {...}, college: {...}}
*/
```

Comment: At that point you need to write your own parser.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to writing your own parser from scratch, you might consider interpreting the user input as [YAML](https://yaml.org). For example, the Node.js command `require("js-yaml").load(input)` converts your example input into the following Javascript object:

```js
{
  name: 'John,',
  age: '20,',
  products: [ { id: 100, name: 'flower' }, { id: 101, name: 'snack' } ],
  home: 'New York,',
  education: {
    highSchool: { name: 'Stuyvesant High School', GPA: 3.2 },
    college: { name: 'Fordham University', GPA: 2.8 }
  }
}
```

Except for the trailing commas at the end of the string-valued properties, that is what you want. Either educate your users to leave these commas out, or write a pre-processor that removes them before calling the `.load` function of [`js-yaml`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-yaml).

Comment: Thank you, this one helps me solve the problem.
Solution is:
```if (input.startsWith("{")) input = `{${input}}`;
output = require("js-yaml").load(input)
```